# If a specific app doesn't require full network access permission means it's completely privacy safe?

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android, permissions, google-apps

If they can't access internet, they can't steal my data in the back which is safe right? I wanna try this file encryption app from play store. Before i proceed, i wanna make sure that the app itself is completely safe. It's called SSE encryption app.

Comment: Give us the link of the app.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paranoiaworks.unicus.android.sse&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dssi+encryption+app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_CHAcVqH2IoymuQST24zwDw

Comment: You're misinformed at some part, as I see it. While it is true that if an app hasn't declared network access permissions then it cannot contact its mothership, should it need to, but it is far from considered safe. Tell me, what safeguards do you have to stop such an app from [encrypting your data and demand ransom](http://www.darkreading.com/simplocker-first-ever-data-encrypting-ransomware-for-android/d/d-id/1269455)?

Comment: How can they encrypt and demand ransom when it can't communicate with the developer? Even if they encrypt the file and demand ransom, as long as the file is encrypted in my local storage, i don't care if it's non accessible, i just don't want some random stranger put hands on it!

Comment: That's not hard to do IMO. A cracker needs to be selective during programming of the ransomware. The app can encrypt data, create a string, and ask ransom of some dollars. In instructions, you would be told to enter that string onto a web-portal to receive further instructions to pay ransom. Once you are done paying your money, you would be provided an unlock key which you can put into a corresponding area of the installed app. Ransom complete. Is it hard? I just gave a possible scenario.

Comment: I understand. Like i said, If that happens, as long as the encrypted non accessible file is in my local storage, I'm not gonna pay him a cent, i would just delete the file by myself and show him the finger. All i need to know, Is there a way a developer can physically put hands on the said encrypted non accessible file or any file in my local storage for that matter?

Comment: No, if the developer doesn't know you personally and there is no network access permission declared, then chances are low to none. You can show the finger or whatsoever you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ***all*** apps always have the ability to access the internet. The permission can be misleading. It has to do with viewing other devices on a network and the network details.
What you can do is right after downloading the app, put your phone in airplane mode. That will prevent any data from leaving the phone, then uninstall it before turning airplane mode off.

Although in all reality, unless you're running `Paranoid Android`, your data is never truly safe, and even then it isn't perfect.

Comment: By "Paranoid Android" are you referring to the famous PA  ROM or you literally meant being 'Paranoid'?

Comment: What's this "Paranoid android"? Will it be more privacy secured to switch from stock android?

Comment: @firelord Meant the ROM.

Comment: @Ygr paranoid android is a custom ROM that secures your phone FAR better than the stock ROM. However, apps still have the same abilities, so for the context of this question, it wouldn't benefit you much. However, it makes it nearly impossible (note nearly, nothing can be unhackable) for someone to deliberately hack into your phone without your knowledge.